# Spring Boot app deployed to Heroku doesn't locate its' thymeleaf views

Tags: java, spring, heroku, spring-boot, thymeleaf

My Spring Boot app runs perfectly at `localhost` but when I'm deploying it to Heroku, my app's controller stops seeing the views which are normally located at /templates/ directory. Why does this happen? How can I be sure that heroku actually uploads and compiles my views? If it does, should I change actual values of @RequestMapping of my @Controller class in order to make them reachable when they are at heroku?

You can find my whole working webapp here: https://github.com/slavicketernity/testik56

Here is my uploaded and runnung app: https://testik56app.herokuapp.com/login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you deploying this application as a .jar? I have seen some infrastructures require that you deploy applications as a .war to provide access to your webpage directory.

If that is the issue you can apply the war plugin via gradle.
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/war_plugin.html

Comment: I'm deploying it as an app with an embedded tomcat container. This means, it is neither .jar, nor .war. Deploying it, I was using these instructions: [link](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-spring-boot-apps-to-heroku)

Comment: Right. I am familiar with the embedded tomcat container. Can you send a printout of the logs?

Comment: please, take a look at my full log of initializing the app after rebooting its 'dyno' and my first attempt to run it (visiting the app's link) [here](https://nwethik.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/log93000.txt)

Comment: sure, here it is: `2017-06-01T16:46:16.206102+00:00 app[web.1]: 2017-06-01 16:46:16.202 ERROR 4 --- [io-40292-exec-3] org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine
   : [THYMELEAF][http-nio-40292-exec-3] Exception processing template "/login": Error resolving template "/login", template might not exi
st or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
2017-06-01T16:46:16.206133+00:00 app[web.1]: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "/login", template
 might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers`

Comment: Oh. you may have to put your template files in the webapp directory. 
src/main/webapp/
That should fix the issue.

Comment: I was unsuccessful to do this. I couldn't make SpringBoot look in src/main/webapp folder for views. For me, even setting a custom TemplateResolver in @Configuration class didn't help. I have tried another approach - to make a 'fat jar' of my application and upload it to heroku. In Intellij Idea the app runs well. However, when I run the .jar even locally, it still gives me the Error Page `There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Error resolving template "/login", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers`

Comment: I mark your reply as an answer because this is true that Heroku works nicely with `.war` and behaves badly with absolutely the same app wrapped in `.jar`. I believe I have solved this issue by setting the `<package>war</package>` in my `pom.xml`

Answer (score 17):

In my case it was fault of the slashes on the beginning of the String returned by Controller's method with template location.

After I changed the String returned by controller's methods from

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/orders/{orderId}/create_entry")
String create(@PathVariable String orderId) {
    return "/order_entries/create";
}
```

to

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/orders/{orderId}/create_entry")
String create(@PathVariable String orderId) {
    return "order_entries/create";
}
```

then it started to work.

Comment: this is a good notion. I'm not sure that this was my case, but, this slash topic is really one of the most error-prones. The initial slash points to the root of the project classpath, while no initial slash makes the path relative.